# HTML coding and/or echo function inside a php file. Whats the difference?

Tags: php, html

Consider a for loop in `PHP` file. I am printing the `HTML` coding in two ways.

**Method 1**: `HTML` coding...

```html
<?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { ?>
    <b>Hello</b><br />
<?php } ?>
```

**Method 2**: Pure `PHP` coding...

```html
<?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo "<b>Hello</b><br />";
}
```

Both methods are working perfectly fine. I want to know these:

- **Which has less processing time?**
- Is there any correct way of representation? Am I using it the wrong way?
- Which method do the programmers prefer to work with? Why?
- Whats the overall difference?

Comment: It is good to separate the logic from the output. For this, you can use templaters such as twig, Smarty...

Comment: both are good , both working weary well , any one you can use, but most preferred second

Comment: Ask yourself: which is more readable and easier to write (especially once you start adding quote characters inside of that HTML...)

Comment: thank you guys... I want to know, which works faster with less processing time...

Comment: That's virtually irrelevant. You're not going to see any practical performance difference from either. Also: test it yourself.

Comment: I vote for option 3 - writing html rather than echoing it, but using phps alternative 'templating' syntax for blocks, eg `<?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++):?> <p>some html</p><?php endfor;?>`, `while():endwhile; if():endif;` as closing curly braces interspersed with html are hard to read. Performance differences will be so negligible they are not worth considering

Comment: I'd like the first one, becuse i am using my own framework, and i am using views like templates. So my IDE can indent the code, syntax highlights, and it's more readable for me.

Comment: If all you do is echo static HTML, there's no reason why that should be done by PHP. In templates `foreach ($arr as $val): ?>` followed by `<b>Some markup</b>` and an `<?php endforeach;` is really common, but in the end, it's a matter of personal preference

Comment: `+1` Many people might have the same question! `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Which has less processing time?**
   Both have the same processing time!
2. **Is there any correct way of representation? Am I using it the wrong way?**
   Depends on the user. Both are correct.
3. **Which method do the programmers prefer to work with? Why?**
   As a developer, I personally prefer the HTML version, as it is easy to work on HTML rather than inside `"`s. If you are working with both FrontEnd Architects and PHP Developers, the HTML way is preferred for the FrontEnders... `:)`
4. **Whats the overall difference?**
   Readability? The HTML version has many advantages when you are using in an IDE, like the IDE can autosuggest the tags, attributes, values, etc. Also, if you are using complex quotes, like in mixture of `'` and `"`, PHP doesn't need to come inside.

Comment: I really accept your answers. But, I really want to know the exact processing time difference. This makes a lot of difference for me...

Comment: Why don't you make a test with yourself? see `microtime` function in manual.

Comment: Why not try it yourself in your environment? Coz in my local WAMP Server, I don't find any difference, literally. But if you are scaling for a large amount of data, you have to check it with the live data.

Comment: @cuSK: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. **If** there is a measurable difference in processing time, it depends on a lot of things, but the first version is likely to be a _bit_ slower

Comment: @cuSK: The difference is minimal, so if you're looking at ways to speed up your code, you're barking up the wrong tree. But to answer your question: My hunch seemed to be correct, the all-PHP version is slightly faster: https://eval.in/210505 vs https://eval.in/210506

Comment: @lolka_bolka i'm very sorry, i dont know to use `microtime` functionality...

Comment: @cuSK Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880149/best-way-to-measure-and-refine-performance-with-php

Comment: You seem to believe that one might be faster than the other: if you can actually demonstrate a measurable difference in speed, I'll be very surprised

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem that worked. pure php is faster...

Comment: And if the processing time between those two makes a lot of difference to you, then clearly there are no other possible bottlenecks anywhere in your code.... except I can see you use post-increment rather than pre-increment, which suggests you aren't even aware of that tiny optimisation which will have a more significant effect of execution time of your code that dropping out of php/echo will

Comment: @PraveenKumar i checked it. Thank you :) Chennai-vasi

Comment: @cuSK Okay, my apologies. Pure PHP is faster, but for `10000` iterations, there's a difference of 0.01 second or something, if it is negligible for you, you can use the `HTML` version! `:)`

Comment: Note that a single test of each won't actually tell you which is faster; you'll need to test over millions of iterations to get an accurate timing

Comment: @cuSK Thalaivaa! Romba nandri! `:D`

Comment: @MarkBaker I didn't knew that until now. That was really informative... Thank you very much...

Comment: Like @MarkBaker said, it also depends on your environment and the amount of data is stored. If the data is minimal and the difference is negligible, you can use the HTML version as it is more readable. There are a lot of other advantages too! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar accept pannitaen... accept panna marandhe poyitaen...

Comment: @cuSK: Do realize that, as Mark pointed out, the eval I posted is ***not*** conclusive because: 1) Differences between PHP versions could change the results. 2) It's a test that, in no way represents real-life use of PHP (you're not echoing variables, for one). 3) Depending on what the output is (how long, single/double quotes), the results can vary. 4) Each run is different, you'll only get a meaningful result after a larger, more varied data-set and a couple of million iterations on various setups. 5) Caching and other unknowns can make all the difference in the world, too. 6) Entropy

Comment: With Entropy I mean that the slightest difference on the server can influence the processing time it takes... there's just too many variables to draw conclusions from one simple test