# Large PHP session slowing down web application

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a web application where complex permissions determine whether or not a user has access to each of thousands of different files. A user can see all files, but there is an indicator to open files that they have access to. A user has access to a file if someone else in their organization has access to it, or if someone that they are in a collaboration with has shared access to that file.

Right now, I have a complex PHP function that generates a large PHP session by building arrays of the files a user has access to, either in their organization or their collaborations, and merging these access arrays. When these files are displayed to the user, PHP checks this array to see if they have access, and if they do, it adds the button to open the file. I am doing it this way because running the query to check for access for each individual file ended up taking way too long when displaying long file lists, and PHP's in_array() was substantially faster.

**The problem is...**

The php session has gotten so large that it seems to be slowing down simple website functions to a crawl, and I need to think of a new way to do this.

**My question is...**

What would be the best way to replace PHP sessions for storing file permissions and file locations for thousands of files a user has access to, so that when lists of files are being displayed, PHP can rapidly retrieve this information, without needing to run a query for each individual file?

Comment: Have you considered using memcached to store the array? Also, have you determined which part of your access setup is actually causing the gridlock?

Comment: Sometimes the lists of files being displayed can be hundreds long. When those files are being displayed, for each file, PHP would need to run a query to see if they have access to it, if their organization has access to it, and then query each of that user's collaborations to see if any of them have access to it. This is far to many separate queries, and it takes a really long time. Having one big pre-generated array of access is much faster. Might not be the best way, but it's faster than running several queries for each file.

Comment: Is it impossible to whittle the querying down to fewer (one?) queries? Also, note the comment you responded to I deleted (before your response), but it is helpful regardless. Also, paging results could help, or offloading it to another process and loading the response after it's ready (a la travel sites, although that's a bit of an extreme approach).

Comment: Chuck's method seems like it would be able to do that... storing the session in the database and querying for all articles a user has access to at the time the file list is being displayed, and then checking to see if each file is in that result array. Does that approach sound like it would be the most efficient?

Comment: I think, before you do anything, first find out where the gridlock is occurring (http://xdebug.org/), and treat the root of the problem. Offloading the currently session-based array into a database field, at least on it's face, doesn't seem to me to induce a more efficient approach, but I'm not sure either. First find out where the actual problem lies.

Comment: There's also PHP's APC - http://pecl.php.net/package/APC. From the page: *APC is a free, open, and robust framework for caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code.* Probably more than you're looking for, but worth a look. This question is also worth looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720/find-out-where-your-php-code-is-slowing-down-performance-issue

Comment: What's the array's structure and how large is the array?

Comment: The array stores only the files the user has access to, and the structure is userId, fileId, filepath. For users with the largest access, the array is currently 10,000+ items large, which results in a 17mb PHP session which I have set to be stored in a file on the server because otherwise it would use up way too much RAM. Only a few users have that much access, so for the majority of users, the session is much smaller and things run smoothly. But obviously a 17mb session is pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

Hm, without knowing the full scope of the problem, I'd suggest adding a `Sessions` table in your database and include a `FilePermissions` field and a `UserId` field.

This field would store a json representation of your permissions structure. This would only require one call to the database and the majority of the processing would take place while parsing the json data server-side (which shouldn't be much overhead at all).

This is a standard way to reduce the size of client-side session information. A good rule of thumb is putting anything in the `Sessions` table that exposes the logic of your application.

**Update**

I would only store the files that they **do** have access to in the json field. Non-existence can be assumed as prohibiting them from accessing the files. This would again reduce the performance footprint.

This would only work if there isn't a complex permissions structure (like each file has permissions for read and write). If it doesn't, I'd say you're in the clear.

Comment: So to clarify what you are suggesting, I would then query the database session table for all files a user has access to at the time of each file list being displayed, and then for each file in the list, check that result array for access?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I've used something similar for dynamic form generation and it worked great. See my post to make it even less resource intensive.

Comment: This isn't as different from sessions, now, is it? Sessions could also contain just the files that the user has access to, and this would probably be faster than a database access to fetch a JSON entry plus a decode of the JSON entry.

Comment: @IvanVučica PHP sessions work faster, but the sheer size of the sessions needed for my application were causing the entire system to be bogged down, so another approach is needed. I need to store permissions for every file at once because generating those permissions on the fly would be too costly, as they can get fairly complex.

Comment: @Chuck - I implemented your approach, but it seems that the single database query for the serialized permissions and then unserializing the data takes roughly 8 seconds, give or take a few. This solves the problem of the application being bogged down, but seems to introduce a new problem of an initial 8+ second lag when loading lists of files. Do you know of a possible solution to this?

Comment: @skiindude22 Could you post your JSON data structure? We may be able to optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is much you can do. Perhaps `memcached` can help, but I haven't used it (although, from what I heard, that's what it's used for).

You could persist the array in a file, although, as far as I know, that's exactly what sessions do.

You could also try using [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) to persist user data in-memory between script launches.

Do you really need the entire list of user's permissions in one single array? That is, do you always display thousands of files to the user? If so, why? Would it be possible to redesign the system using AJAX to lazily fetch only a portion of files?

---

UPDATE: Another idea.

You could also precalculate permissions of the user for each file and store that in the database. Table could be called `FilesPermittedPerUser` and have two-column primary key `userID / fileID`. This will create an index that is sorted first by `userID`, then by `fileID`. A two-column key would also enforce uniqueness of entries.

Since it would then be indexed by user, you can simply `ORDER BY userID` and `LIMIT 10, 10` to list only files 10-20. Fetching only parts of the list via AJAX would mean you'd never cause the terrible memory load that your scripts currently cause.

It would only require that whenever permissions of the file are updated (for example, file is created, file is deleted, group permissions are changed, group membership of user is changed, group membership of file is changed...) you would have to update the table. I suspect this should not be too difficult. Just make sure you do cache update in a transaction, to preserve operation atomicity.

You may also want to organize the filesystem in folders. It makes very little sense to just throw tons of files at users and have to maintain them at all times. Try throwing 10.000 files at Explorer/Finder/Nautilus and see what happens when you open that folder. Nothing nice, and they get to keep the memory around - and with PHP you don't.

Final idea (although you probably don't have to go to these extremes): rewrite filesystem APIs in something that isn't PHP and can keep the permission data around. Use PHP only to forward requests to this custom server that runs on a different.

Comment: The whole system is using AJAX to retrieve the file lists, and PHP is determining which of those files they have access to. They don't need to be displayed all at once, but access needs to be rapidly determined at the time lists are displayed. I have never used memcached, I'll have to look into it!

Comment: I updated the answer with more ideas, based on other people's answers and comments on this page, as well as your comments.