# find which part of php code processes high

Tags: php, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out where your PHP code is slowing down (Performance Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720/find-out-where-your-php-code-is-slowing-down-performance-issue)

I have a program written fully in PHP language
when I run it with Apache it takes 3 seconds to make a response!!! It's too high
How can I find out which part of my codes processes high?!  Is there any tools to do that?
php uses 100% of my CPU resource for 3-4 seconds

Comment: Generic rules are because of external resource like database, file open, xml file open, real-time content scrapping on an external site, doggy SQL

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) to [profile](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) your script