# What performance improvements can I make to Symfony + Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, symfony1, cpu-speed

I've recently built a reasonably complex database application for a university handling almost 200 tables. Some tables can (e.g. Publications) hold 30 or more fields and store 10 one-to-one FK relations and up to 2 or 3 many-to-many FK relations (using crossreference-ref tables). I use integer IDs throughout and normalisation has been key every step of the way. AJAX is minimal and most pages are standard CRUD forms/processes.

I used Symfony 1.4, and Doctrine ORM 1.2, MySQL, PHP.

While the benefits to development time and ease of maintenance have been enormous (in using an MVC and ORM), we've been having problems with speed. That is, when we have more than a few users logged in and active at any one time the application slows considerbly (up to 20 seconds to save or edit a record).

We're currently engaged in discussions with our SysAdmin but they say that we should have more than enough power. With 6 or more users engaged in activity, we end up queuing 4 CPUs in a virtual server environment while memory usage is low (no bleeds).

Of course, we're considering multi-threading our mySQL application (if this will help), refining our code (though much of it is generated by the MVC) and refining our cache usage (this could be better, though the majority of the screen used is user-login specific and dynamic); we've installed APC, extra memory, de-fragmented our database, I've tried unsetting all recordsets (though I understand this is now automatic within the ORM), instigating manual garbage recycling...

But the question I'm asking is whether mySQL, PHP, and Symfony MVC was actually a poor choice for developing an application of this size in the first place? If so, what do people normally use/recommend for a web-based database interface application of this kind of size/complexity?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I meant multi-channeling our mySQL database..

Comment: So did you determine which process eats up the resources? It's pointless to optimize without seeing what tears down the memory and CPU. Also, what guarantee do you have that your queries are optimal? Number of tables is nothing, what matters is the size of the data, how it's indexed which determines size of the b-trees and the memory consumption (assuming you're using InnoDB with large enough buffer_pool_size). So answering your question is difficult and anyone can just guess what's wrong. It's too early to blame it on doctrine or php, check which process eats up resources first.

Comment: If you are otherwise happy with your system I'd look to optimize it before chucking it.  There are many factors. First thought would be that you might not have the proper indexes on your databases for the queries you are running. Turn on your slow query log, examine the queries you find there, use the explain command to suss out whether the slow queries are performing unindexed searches.  Add indexes as necessary.

Comment: Dear N.B. and AllInOne, I have indexed all FK relations. There aren't any queries that are unindexed. Regarding slow queries, yes you're right but the majority of them are built by Symfony. I do apply table_methods on most list queries with root alias extensions and admittedly I do tend to use the algebraic syntax for SQL joins (is that REALLY bad??).

Comment: My question, however, was really more general than asking for a pinpoint of what could be wrong. I've not built a system as large as this on my own before and I was wondering if there were better/more recommendable technologies out there to do this sort of thing? Perhaps not..

Comment: Thank you both for your responses, I'll be looking at the slow query log asap though I'm not certain it'll tell me anything more than the Symfony debug bar (highlights slow queries in orange). I'll look into the buffer_pool_size, also...

Comment: So basically there are no queries that are slow, which you haven't checked, you haven't checked what process takes up CPU time (could be that doctrine runs db analysis every time someone connects), you only have 200 tables which makes you think it's a large project and indexing everything without running queries trough `EXPLAIN` procedure makes you think you've done everything right? I personally don't know what technology one would recommend, but who guarantees you won't make same mistakes?

Comment: I'm asking for advice, not chippy comments. At no point did I claim to be any kind of expert. Thank you for your input so far but please go get your superiority points elsewhere :) The database model is relational, all IDs are integer PKs and have indexes relating them. The MVC uses these, as does my code. Nowhere (except when filtering/searching) do we use unindexed joins. If this is wrong or I'm not pointing something out, please tell me.

Comment: Also, as I think I pointed out in the question, my question was more general: is Symfony/php/mySQL a sufficient technology to run this size of application. The answer appears to be yes. Considering everything it would seem that our server is just not delivering enough oophm as the performance issues are severe.

Comment: Also, we have xdebug running on our dev server and error reports are included in the symfony debug reports. As I pointed out slow queries are highlighted in orange (depending on the setting, of course) and we've had nothing overtly noticable.

Comment: Symfony is fine for this. Have you confirmed your opcode cache as working? How about FastCGI etc, so PHP processes stay memory resident for a while? (In general for a question of this kind, table sizes are more important to mention than numbers of tables - unless you are joining all 200 together! Equally, it's better to mention how much memory you now have in your server, rather than the fact that you've "installed extra".

Comment: Also: modify your dev front controller so you can safely deploy it (using IP filtering) and then use the slow query in the debug toolbar as per @AllInOne's advice on your live server. This saves the hassle of trying to replicate multiple users on a dev box.

Comment: Thanks, halfer. I'll look into the "opcode cache" you mention. I do have APC running, and fairly sure FastCGI is in there (I'll check). As regards memory we have just under 4GB. There are just under 200 tables with between 10-40 fields, averaging probably at about 10-15. Records from 8000 to 172000 at the high end range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Symfony or Doctrine. However, there are certainly larger sites than yours that are built on these projects. DailyMotion for instance uses both, and it serves a heck of a lot more than a few simultaneous users.

Likewise, PHP and MySQL are used on sites as large as Wikipedia, so scalability should not be a problem. (BTW, MySQL should be multithreaded by default—one thread per connection.)

Of course, reasonable performance is relative. If you're trying to run a site serving 200 concurrent requests off a beige box sitting in a closet, then you may need to optimize your code a lot more than a Fortune 500 company with their own data centers.

The obvious thing to do is actually profile your application and see where the bottleneck is. Profiling MySQL queries is pretty simple, and there are also assorted [PHP profiling tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720/find-out-where-your-php-code-is-slowing-down-performance-issue) like [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). From there you can figure out whether you should switch frameworks, ORMs (or ditch ORM altogether), databases, or refactor some code, or just invest in more processing power.

Comment: Thank you, Lese. This is very helpful. This is the first time I've built anything at this scale and I'm uncertain whether the bottleneck is software (php, ORM, or mySQL) or hardware (the server).

Comment: I'm now looking into installing kcachegrind onto our dev server. Looks like it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to speed up complex database operation is not calling them :).

So analyize which parts of your application you can cache.
Symfony has a pretty well caching system (in symfony2 even better) that can be used pretty granulary.

On database side another way would be to use views or nested sets to store aggregated data.
Try to find parts where this is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, ivoba. I'm not that up on caching in general. Time to look into it more. I guess Symfony documentation is the best source for this..